# Namespace Class clash in C# - looking for suggestions

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

I'm building a generic articles framework and my namespace names are clashing with my entities:

**Namespace: MyCompany.Articles.Modules**

**Class: Articles, Article**

Any suggestions to how this can be avoided? According to MS I should use the following format: `<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]`.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the `Articles` class for? Collection of `Article`?

Comment: Yep, a collection of articles: TList<Article>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution is to rename your `Articles` class to `ArticleCollection`, assuming that class is a collection of `Article` instances.

This convention is consistent with the .NET Framework and is easy to read.

---

Since the class is being generated automatically a manual rename is not the best solution.

You can change the namespace to something more broader:

```
[MyCompany].[MyProduct].Dao
```

or if it spans all the products in the company:

```
[MyCompany].Common.Dao
```

where `Dao` means Data Access Objects.

Comment: That will be my assumption too :P

Comment: Hi thanks. The Articles class is generated in .NetTiers automatically using the db table named "Articles" so it seems to be easier to change the namespace of the Modules project. The Modules project is using the auto-generated projects from .NetTiers.

Comment: The idea is to call the Articles system something unique other than just Articles - give it a product name. I can follow that. Cheers.